# Qualtrics -- Save variable as answer

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm trying to implement some custom javascript in order to save a variable I initialize as the answer to a particular question.

I've created a multiple choice question, and limited it to one possible answer: "Save responses". 
I've implemented the following code, trying to save a string variable as the question's answer:

```
  this.questionclick = function(event,element) {
  var toSave = "save this string";
  this.setChoiceValue(1, toSave);
```

}

However, this isn't saving the variable "toSave" to the question.
There's pretty scant documentation on qualtrics' API, so I'm hoping someone here has encountered this problem and can provide an example solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the text value of an answer option through JavaScript. Qualtrics keeps that server side.

You could do the the opposite, by making the text value of the answer option "save this string" then using JavaScript to change that label from "save this string" to "Save responses" when the question loads. The html structure is slightly different under jfe so you need to account for that.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    var jfe = false;
    if(window.location.pathname.match(/^\/jfe/)) jfe = true;

    var downArg = 0;
    if(jfe) downArg++;

    $(this.questionId).down('.LabelWrapper').down(downArg).update("Save responses");
});
```

**EDIT:**
To answer a question in comment below - If you want to save a JavaScript variable in Qualtrics, first initialize the variable in the survey flow, then save it in the JavaScript like this:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('myvar', value);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I adapt that code for my survey, I get an error because $(this.questionId).down('.LabelWrapper')  is undefined, so the rest of that line doesn't work. What exactly is the "down" command? According to the javascript API, $(this.questionId) returns a string.

Comment: No, this.questionId is a string (the question id). $(this.questionId) returns the question element (a div), then down searches down the DOM tree within the question element and returns the first element with the class LabelWrapper. Finally, the next down goes down 1 (if SE) or 2 (if JFE) levels from the first LabelWrapper element, which is the element that contains the label. This assumes you have a multiple choice question with one choice. It works fine for me. As long as you have a MC with at least one choice you should have an element with the class LabelWrapper.

Comment: Thanks again for this; I've gotten the variable to be displayed next to the radio button, but when I submit the survey, the new variable -- the one the choice text changes to -- isn't saved; instead, it just saves whatever name I gave the radio button in the first place. Did you do anything to adjust for that?